# Htaccess rewrite does not work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was told that this is the right way to redirect anyone who is trying to open:

/users/username/something.txt

But i can't seem to get it work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.txt$ /notallowed.html [F,L,NC]
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: Back up and tell us what you're *trying* to do. At the moment, there's no way to know if what you were *told* is good or bad.

Comment: Im trying to block out anyone who tries to open the users .txt file.

Comment: Then mod_rewrite probably isn't want you're looking for. I suggest `chmod o-r`. Other than that, you're probably better off using `<Location>` or `<Directory>` if possible, with a `deny from all`, which will send a proper 403. You can set up an error document to customize the 403, of course.

Comment: Hmm, okay, i will try the <Location> way. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to deny users from all TXT files would be to use something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

However, the code you have there should work for all intents and purposes. Depending on your server configuration, however, you may need to add "Options +FollowSymLinks".

If you decide to go the FilesMatch route, you can use ErrorDocument to control what page the user is taken to.